# How do I configure my Rails app (using Puma) to serve over HTTPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, configuration, puma

I'm setting up a Rails application with Puma, I can't seem to make it serve over HTTPS.
I've tried maybe fifteen different guides and stack over flow answers, but neither of them have worked for me.
Now, I can't serve regular HTTP either, even when reverting the configuration.

What I've tried:

config/puma.rb

```
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

my_key = "#{File.join(Rails.root, 'public', '.well-known', 'privkey.pem')}"
my_crt = "#{File.join(Rails.root, 'public', '.well-known', 'cert.pem')}"

ssl_bind(
  'mydomain.com',
  3000,
  key: my_key,
  cert: my_crt,
  verify_mode: 'peer'
)
```

`mydomain.com` is of course replaced by the proper domain name.

config/application.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

I've put my certificate and private key in `public/.well-known`. The files were generated using Certbot.
Folder contents:

```
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

The files were generated using Certbot.

The resulting error message is as follows:
`HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>`

What am I doing wrong?

-

Also, when resetting my configuration and testing out the site, I get the same error message.
What can be done about that?

**SOLUTION:**
Check out the comments in the reply by Jan Vítek to see how this was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems here:

1. This is not why it is not working, but please move your private key out of the `/public` path. It is not much private there.
2. You are binding the SSL to the same port as the HTTP server
3. You are binding the SSL to `whatever.domain`. It can bring many problems. If there is a NAT the app has no interface to bind to. If there is the server's FQDN in `/etc/hosts` it would bind to the localhost interface a you wouldn't be able to access it from the internet. If it actually bound to the interface with IP resolved from that domain, you might have problems accessing the app locally. Just change it to `0.0.0.0` for now and when you have it working you can experiment with this attribute.
4. SSL verify mode `peer` would verify client certificates. I'm not sure if it is your intention but it would require `:ca` option to be passed to `ssl_bind()` with a path to your CA certificate
5. You don't say if it is for development or production purposes. For production you might want to consider Apache + Passenger or Nginx + Passenger where the HTTPs would have been handled by the web server (Apache or Nginx)

Anyway I created a new Rails 7 application, placed my crt and key to `config/ssl/` and modified only the `config/puma.rb`

```rb
#config/puma.rb
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', 3001, {
  key: 'config/ssl/dev.mydomain.com.key',
  cert: 'config/ssl/fullchain.cer',
  verify_mode: 'none'
}

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Then simple `rails s` and I am able to connect to `https://dev.mydomain.com:3001`. Make sure to explicitly call `https://`.

Comment: Yea, putting the private key in "public" was a last ditch attempt at getting it to work - just to see. Doesn't matter until I can get the server to provide a proper response besides "not secure" anyways.
Currently, I'm running in development environment.
My domain name resolves properly, so I'm not sure if there should be a problem there...

Comment: I tried creating a new rails project, copying my cert + key over to the new project, then changed the puma config as you suggested, but nothing changes.
I have port forwarding set up for 80 and 443 to 3000 and 3001, respectively.
I get "unreachable" for port 3001, and SSL protocol error for 3000.
That is both for when domain is set to "0.0.0.0" and the domain I use.

Comment: When you run the server, does it say `Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:3001?cert=...`?

Comment: No. `Listening on http://[my public IP]:3000` with my public IP. Rails version is 7.0.4.2, if that helps.

Comment: That's the problem. Are you sure you are passing only one `ssl_bind` in `config/puma.rb` and there is address `0.0.0.0` and port `3001`? If you don't want to listen on 0.0.0.0 and your port forwarding is local, listen on localhost. If the port forwarding is on your router, listen on the IP address of the server which is in the same subnet as the router.

Comment: Did not notice that it doesn't listen on `ssl://` at all, only `http://`. Where did it get `[your public IP]`? Do you have the `config/puma.rb` exactly the same as I posted?

Comment: "Where did it get [your public IP]?" what was I needed to solve this - thanks for the help.
When running the server I called `rails server -b [my domain name]`, but running a plain `rails server` instead did the trick, both for the test project, as well as the actual application. Much appreciated.